# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault connection refused

Tags: java, apache, web-services, postgresql, axis2c

I'm getting the following error while tryng to suscribe to a service from client app.
Can somebody tell me the reason for this exception?

Thanks in advance

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Conexión rehusada

```
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)

        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)

        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)

        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)

        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)

        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)

        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)

        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)

        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)

        at com.tissat.echo.wsdl.EchoServiceStub.suscribe(EchoServiceStub.java:772)

        at com.tissat.echo.servicios.ServicioLisa.cliSuscribirse(ServicioLisa.java:122)

        at com.tissat.echo.servicios.ClienteLisa.Conectar(ClienteLisa.java:23)

        at com.tissat.echo.rmi.ServidorLisaTomcat.connectSuscription(ServidorLisaTomcat.java:150)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)

        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)

        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)

        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)

        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)

        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)

        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada

```
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)

        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)

        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)

        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)

        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:130)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)

        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)

        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)

        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)

        ... 26 more
```

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Conexión rehusada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection refused means the following:

> The host exists, nothing is listening for connections on that port.
>   Alternatively, a firewall is blocking that port.

More at: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/client-side-axis.html

Answer (score 1):

We faced similar issue and we were getting Read Time Out while trying to invoke a secured webservice, after a long analysis we found out that there was a mismatch in the transport protocol version. Web-service was servicing on http1.0 and we were invoking it using http1.1. We modified the protocol version in our client code which resolves this issue:

Below is the code to specify http version-1.0 
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION, org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Service` is not running where you think it is running. Check whether it is running properly in the desired port. That's why `ConnectionRefused` Exception is thrown. Make sure you don't have firewall blocking the port.

> if service on that machine has **NOT** created a socket and is **NOT** listening on that port.you will see the message connection refused.