# Axis 2 Error :- org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have gone through [this posted question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950559/org-apache-axis2-axisfault-connection-refused), however my issue is different:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
>   Premature end of file encountered at
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
>
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
>   Premature end of file encountered     at
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)  at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:347)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)

Can anybody help me out please what I'm missing as this is working perfectly fine in my local machine. But failing onto my server environment.

Please let me know if more details are required.
I had added this jars in my server Web-Inf :

[image]

Please have a look at this SOAP request that we are hitting :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soap:Header>
<tem:UserAuth>
       <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:UserName>?</tem:UserName>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:Password>?</tem:Password>
      </tem:UserAuth>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:Cities/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Well, the request message and the relevant code should be in your question to check them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you please let me know what more details should i share .... sorry for a novice question

Comment: Well, we don't know the content of the message that's triggering that error. When is it happening? What are you trying to do? I assume, consuming a web service you built with axis2... please share the SOAP request

Comment: I have added the SOAP request we are hitting.